# Laravel Notifications - How to send a link via SMS

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

I'm using Laravel Notification via Nexmo to send SMS. Following the docs, I can compose my message content like:

```
/**
 * Get the Nexmo / SMS representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return NexmoMessage
 */
public function toNexmo($notifiable)
{
    return (new NexmoMessage)
                ->content('Your SMS message content');
}
```

However, I need to send a link in the SMS content.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you just insert the link, like `Go to http://stackoverflow.com and be happy`, it works or not?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte strangely it works in some Android SMS app and others not...

Comment: Felippe Duarte, if the link is comes from a variable?